# GitHub pages do not appear

Tags: github

I have added a `gh-pages` branch to [a project on GitHub](https://github.com/raphink/augeas-talks/tree/gh-pages), but the GitHub pages are [not appearing](http://raphink.github.com/augeas-talks).

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Has this been solved? The pages look up

Answer (score 5):

On your repository, there is settings link. Open it.
[image: Settings menu on top right]

Scroll down a bit, there is GitHub Pages settings.
[image: Scroll down a bit]

Try to select different source from "Select source" dropdown/combobox and save. Then change it again into gh-pages branch and don't forget to save.

This fix my head-banging-404-waiting-nothing-happening-after-hours-refreshing

Comment: This was it for me too. When I first pushed the gh-pages branch, the interface makes it look like that branch is being published. But it isn't until you switch it to master, and then back to gh-pages that it's actually published.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub Pages often take a few minutes to show up, especially on the first creation of the `gh-pages` branch. From the [default 404 page](http://github.github.com/404.html):

> ### There isn't a GitHub Page hosted here, sorry.
>
> #### Are you trying to publish one?
>
> We'll send you an email when your page has been built. **It may take up to ten minutes until your page is available.**

(emphasis added)