# How can casing for page headers on GitHub wikis be controlled?

Tags: wiki, github

Is there a way to escape the apparent forced [sentence casing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Usage) for the title on a GitHub wiki page?

The wiki seems to be based on [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum), and it seems to force sentence casing for titles. Attempts to change the title to something other than sentence casing, like proper casing for [initialisms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aGlossary#initialism), ([example](https://github.com/deldy/geekhub/wiki/API), attempted change from "Api" to "API") have no effect. Editing the body of the page works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually working. There is an update delay on the order of 10 minutes<sup>1</sup>

<sub>[1] Source: TBD</sub>

Comment: Regarding the source: During research, I remember seeing a page referring to an update delay, but I closed the page... I will update when I locate it.

Comment: You may have been reading this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/github-pages-do-not-appear